# Nginx 404 Not Found on registered Route

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-4, mamp

I have some weird issue that I couldn't tell why it lead to that. 
I have a Laravel 4.2 web application running locally on my MAMP on my Mac.

**'/' route is working but the others not working !**

It kept showing

> 404 Not Found

How do I prevent this  ? What should I check ?

Any hints / suggestions on this will mean a lot to me !

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem. I am using php7.2 and nginx 1.14 in ubuntu 18.04. After googling i found the solution. Firstly give a permission to your project .htacces file so that it can be accessed by server. Secondly edit your server scripts for your project which is `/etc/nginx/sites-available` directory. Open your script on the terminal edit the location section which is `location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }`
replace it with `location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }`
. it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Check to see if you have .htaccess file**

After stuck on this more than a day, I've learned that I don't have `.htaccess` in my `public\` folder of my laravel project.

So I created a `public\.htaccess` with this content in there

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

- Reboot my MAMP
- All of that nonsense is no-longer happening.
- Hope this answer help someone like me